# Generate 4 bytes of (pseudo)random data

Tags: c, linux, random

I need to store 4 bytes of (pseudo)random data in a variable in a kernel module. Later this value would be stored on disk. This would not be used for any cryptographic purpose. Just that there should no **discernible** pattern in the values used. It is guaranteed that the structure of which this variable is a member would be allocated through kmalloc. So can I use the following code safely?

```
struct header {
    __u32 magic; 
 /* some other members of the struct */
}; 
struct header *hdr; 
/* Memory initialization through kmalloc*/
hdr->magic = (__u32)(unsigned long)(&hdr->magic);
```

Or should I get data from `random.h` interface?

Comment: "Just that there should no **discernible** pattern in the values used." That is the definition of what a cryptographic RNG needs to produce.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This would be used in some signature scheme for which the only important criteria is that the variable should have some arbitrary value.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I should have had phrased that better :-). As I said in an earlier comment, the variable should have some arbitrary value even if those values are repeated after some time intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look how the drivers for `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` work and imitate their behaviour.